# How to use A-B repeat feature of VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

**Apparently VLC has an [A-B repeat feature](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=27462#p131070), but how do I use it?** There's even a [related feature request](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/4498). I can't find any GUI controls for it (Windows VLC version 1.1.9) I am aware there is a [possible command-line method](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=69043#p69043), but I seek a more user-friendly GUI/keyboard solution.

I ask specifically for VLC, but other free video players that support *both* mirroring (flipping horizontally) and A-B repeat are acceptable.

---

Background info: I have a video of a dance performance I need to practice.

- A-B repeat to concentrate on a single part at a time
- Mirroring to make following it more natural

Comment: +1 for the nice links, and in particular reminding that `vlc` has command line options! Thnx!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In the **View Menu** click **Advanced Controls**. This will display the loop button (A-B) on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: On VLC Windows version has been introduced the shortcut `Shift+L` to obtain the same function as pressing the button. 
To use it, View->Advanced Controls must be displayed and VLC must be not in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 29):

The previous answer is out of date. I have version 2.1.4 (May 2014), on a Mac.

Press **cmd-J** to jump to the start of your loop, then **cmd-shift-L** to mark it.

Press **cmd-J** to jump to the end of your loop, then **cmd-shift-L** to mark it.

You can then watch your loop.

Press **cmd-shift-L** a third time to cancel the loop.

Note that although the dialog for cmd-J says "seconds", **you can enter minutes and seconds normally** (e.g. 4:34).

Comment: This is about as official as documentation on this as exists on the web. Still the UX is so poor I can't figure out why it sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: before finding this answer, attempting to use this feature was extremely frustrating. The A-B repeat option is in the menu and can be clicked, which is equivalent to pressing cmd-shift-L, but there is literally no visual indication of anything happening when you do it.

Answer (score 15):

I believe this can also be accomplished on the CLI:

> --start-time starts the video here; the integer is the number of seconds from the beginning (e.g. 1:30 is written as 90)
>
> --stop-time stops the video here; the integer is the number of seconds from the beginning (e.g. 1:30 is written as 90)
>
> --repeat repeats current item until another item is forced

For example

`vlc movie.avi --start-time 240 --stop-time 560 --repeat`

Source: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/

Comment: Note that VLC correctly processes decimal arguments to these options even though the documentation says they accept integers (tested in version 3.0.9.2).

Answer (score 3):

What I found works is: Tool ---- Customize Interface

Then I added the a-b loop button to my interface.

First Click sets the A Part and the Second sets the B part.

Then you have your loop :D

Answer (score 2):

Play the video and while it's playing Press the 'Loop' button at the point you wish the loop to start (Point A) then press it again at Point B the point you wish it to return to point A.  Pressing a third time clears the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be [**AB Loop Player**](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/ABLoopPlayer/) which runs in the web browser and allows you to fine-tune the A-B loop range and to bookmark and annotate loops for later sessions. Moreover it can be used with YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked right on the mouse, a list appeared and I drew the click on "tools", then I clicked "Personalise Interface". I rolled down to "AB Loop" which I held with the right of the mouse and drew up to the list of buttons up and placed it accordind to my preference... 
Now Im enjoying...

Comment: Please read the answers