# What is the syntax to 'repeat A to B' a video clip using VLC command line?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

We can repeat a clip from point A to point B, called `repeat A to B`, as [discussed here](https://superuser.com/questions/306154/how-to-use-a-b-repeat-feature-of-vlc).

I need to do this using VLC command line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following is what you're looking for:

> --start-time  starts the video here; the integer is the number of seconds from the beginning (e.g. 1:30 is written as 90)
>
> --stop-time  stops the video here; the integer is the number of seconds from the beginning (e.g. 1:30 is written as 90)
>
> --repeat repeats current item until another item is forced

For example

```
vlc movie.avi --start-time 240 --stop-time 560 --repeat
```

Source: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/